# iOS Realm: file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'x86_64'))

Tags: realm, carthage, xcode13

I have updated mac to 11.6 and xcode to 13.0. Realm could not compile so I updated it with carthage to v10.15.1. Now I get this runtime error just after the app launch:

```
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
  Reason: tried: '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework/Realm' (file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64], fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'x86_64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Realm.framework/Realm' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Realm.framework/Realm' (no such file), '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33E61712-D8A9-4D7E-A260-5C096BE08A82/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AC700919-F431-446F-8BEF-FF8D8E5F5BF9/appname.a
```

I guess the key part here is `file does not start with MH_MAGIC[_64]`, but I could not find anything useful about the error.

I tried embedding the library and turning off the embedding, does not affect anything.

Comment: Are you sure your XCode is 10.13? That's an older version at this point - in fact, I don't think there was a 10.13; the versions went from 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 and then 11.

Comment: yeah mistyped it is 13.0

Comment: Do you have any kind of virus protection installed, like Avast? Are you using a free developer account? Did you use Cocoapods? Did you download/update/select you developer certificate in XCode?

Comment: @Jay no I do not have antivirus, how could it affect? I am using payed developer account. And I use carthage. Yes I did.

Comment: Can you include your cartfile in the question? For testing, I would also suggest trying CocoaPods

Comment: Odd, what is the output of `lipo -info /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm.framework/Realm`?

Answer (score 5):

- Realm has 3 targets configured to be built with Carthage (Realm, Realm iOS Static and RealmSwift)
- XCode 13 deprecated a setting for building targets in a manually set order which leads the first 2 targets to be built in a non deterministic order (the 3rd one is always last as it depends on the 1st one). The order and the frequency of it changing seems to be random (it might depend on the specific XCode version)
- When 'Realm' is build before 'Realm iOS Static', the fat framework replaces the one in the xcframework which leads to that error. In the other case, it's the correct one that's built second and overrides the wrong one.
- I guess the solution (apart from upgrading Realm) would be to remove the target 'Realm iOS Static' from the project but it's not straightforward to do with Carthage except by forking Realm

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of realm is `v10.32.0`. `xcode 14.1` is also out.

You need to update your toolset.

Answer (score 0):

The latest upgrade realm version 10.32.0 is compatible with XCode 13.1 and above. If you use the legacy build system, migrate it to the latest one and clean the derivable folder before rebuilding the code. Most of the time derivable keeps track of the older version files and makes conflicts once you update the project tools. Hope this will help